# ImportError: "flask_sqlalchemy" could not be resolved

Tags: python, anaconda

i'm unable to import flask_sqlalchemy even after installing flask-sqlachemy

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
 # ^this line shows error ImportError: "flask_sqlalchemy" could not be resolved

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

i'm not using any virtual environment and flask-sqlalchemy shows already installed

```
(base) sachin@sachin:~/Coding/flask/blog$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.3.20)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/sachin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.1.1)
```

pip freeze shows me its already installed -

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
```

Comment: You're probably running using the system version of python and not Anaconda. There is no other explanation other than you running a different python interpreter than you expect you are

Comment: Try `which python3` and see if it points to anaconda

Comment: yes it is pointing me to anaconda3 .... /home/sachin/anaconda3/bin/python3    what should i do now?

Comment: I just encountered this error in vscode, I'm running WSL workspace. I was able to workaround by selecting system python and then going back to python3.

Comment: If you are using pipenv then try `pipenv install Flask-SQLAlchemy` ! & check Pipfile if the dependency is added. Once I encountered such an issue. Strangely, when I restarted PC then it worked.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error. Changed my system python by doing the following in VS Code:
Under the view menu select 'show command pallet'. One of the commands you can then select from the command palette is 'Python: Select Interpreter'.
Selecting this option will allow you to choose which version of python to use.

Answer (score 5):

This post is pretty old but I found a different solution that might help others out. For me, the issue was my IDE/Python (venv). I am using Visual Studio ver. 1.57.1 as of now on Windows 10.

1. Open Visual Code.
2. Go to 'View' on the toolbar.
3. Click on 'Command Palette...' (or press CTRL + SHIFT + P on Windows).
4. Search for: 'Python Select Interpreter'.
5. Click on: 'Enter interpreter path...' followed by 'Find...'.
6. Go to your (venv) scripts folder: `project_folder/venv/Scripts`.
7. Select `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` inside of your `project_folder/venv/Scripts` folder.

That's all.

The Flask-SQLAlchemy was installed in my virtual environment (venv). But my VSCode was using the system/PC Python interpreter to find the packages instead of the venv.

Hope this helps someone else out.

Comment: Hi, I don't even have a scripts folder within my virtual environment. This is odd. Not sure if there has been an update since. Do you know where it may be now?

Comment: Hi @Connor, I don't know exactly but I advise you to remake your `venv`.

Here's how I did it: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/installation/

On Windows to create a `venv`:
```> mkdir myproject
> cd myproject
> py -3 -m venv venv
```

To active your `venv` on Windows:

```> venv\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, this worked for me:

In cmd, `cd` to your project folder, (for me i had to activate venv, so it showed (env) C:\ etc\etc>)

Then install it here with:

```
pip3 install flask-SQLAlchemy
```

for some reason this took this noob 12 tries, but the give away was there was no sqla files in my site folder, and it kept showing the install had taken place in my python39 folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is for people who do not use Anaconda (I had this issue and I solved it this way)

Your `venv` might be incorrect. Did you copy paste your `venv` from another directory?

`venv` saves path information, so when you run `env\Scripts\activate`, the venv believes it is in a different directory.

It will install the packages in the OLD directory. Make sure you generate a new `py -m venv env` for every app you create rather than copy pasting.

The solution is to delete your current `venv` directory, and run the `py -m venv env` command again. Then the packages will be installed in the current `venv`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a more recent answer. I couldn't find a scripts folder. On my ubuntu machine I did this (in vscode):

1. ctrl + shft + p
2. search select python interpreter
3. enter interpreter path
4. navigate to your-app/venv/python3
5. select python3

This resolved the import issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, resolved using:

1. activate the venv
2. use `pip3` to install `flask` and `flask_sqlalchemy` by running:

```
pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy flask
```

3. And lastly checking if correct python interpreter was selected in vscode from:
   `CMD + Shift + P --> Python: Select Interpreter --> selecting appropriate python version for the venv (preferably python10)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it worked when I changed to Python Interpreter under the command palette of the view tab. If you believe you have installed all required packages and it does not work then definitely try this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have noticed is that if I change the python interpreter from command palette(ctrl+shift+p) to my virtual environment one it does not work. First I tried the command,

```
py -3 -m pip install flask-SQLALchemy
```

Instead of the above command, I upgrade pip by using,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then I tried using the following to import SQLAlchemy.

```
python -m pip install flask-SQLALchemy
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you have done changes, I mean change your python interpreter, delete your env or re-create install packages again. Please close your `app.py` file and re-open it. Some times it still gives your error.